# interchange 2 fields value in My SQL

Tags: mysql, string

I have a database with following format

```
id f1 f2 f3 f4 f5
-------------------------------------
1   a b  c  d  0
```

Here f1, f2,f3 , f4 are of string types and f5 is boolean value , Now I want to replace f2 value with f1 if f5 is 0. i.e. d should be replaced with a and a should have d if field5 is zero   .
tried with various version of replace command , but not able to achieve desired result

Answer (score 0):

You can try using t his:-

```
UPDATE table 
   SET field1=(@temp:=field1), field1 = field2, field2 = @temp
where field5 = 0;
```